# When can I tame a pet?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to tame the Ghost Saber with my hunter. It's level 19. I first tried when I was level 16 and the game told me the saber was too high-level for me to tame. I figured I should reduce the level so that it's yellow to me, but I still got the same message when I tried to tame it at 17.

What are the level requirements for taming a new pet?

Comment: If you are interested in a list of pets (and pictures of them) that you can tame check out http://www.wow-petopia.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't tame a beast that's higher level than you are. So you would need to be level 19 to train that Ghost Saber.